# Laravel Migration Rollback

Tags: php, laravel

I have slight problems with Laravel Migration. I have one table that have parent row itself, and when I try to install passport, passport is rollingback migrations and with one of them is making problems like:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
> update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop table
> if exists `e_categories`)

Table looks like:

```
Schema::create('e_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id');
            $table->primary('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->uuid('parent_id')->nullable();

            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('e_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

And down

```
Schema::dropIfExists('e_categories');
```

BTW in this migration are stored other migrations for categories, but this one is making a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should [drop the Foreign key](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#dropping-foreign-keys) first

in down:

```
$table->dropForeign(['parent_id']);
Schema::dropIfExists('e_categories');
```